# How to speed up character output?

Tags: c++, io, stdout, cout, fmt

I want to make this for loop run faster by optimizing the I/O:

```
for ( int row = 0; row < Y_AxisLen; ++row )
{
    for ( int col = 0; col < X_AxisLen; ++col )
    {
        std::cout << characterMatrix[ row ][ col ];
    }
}
```

`std::vector< std::vector<char> > characterMatrix;` is a matrix and I need to print it out. Is printing one `char` at a time bad for performance? Also, should I use the `{fmt}` library instead of `std::cout`?

Will this work faster?

```
std::array<char, X_AxisLen> rowStr { };

for ( int row = 0; row < Y_AxisLen; ++row )
{
    for ( int col = 0; col < X_AxisLen; ++col )
    {
        rowStr[ col ] = characterMatrix[ row ][ col ];
    }

    std::cout << rowStr.data( );
    // fmt::print( "{}", rowStr.data( ) ); // Or using this one. But will this even work?
}
```

Comment: `std::vector` uses sequential memory, so consider using `cin.write()` to print a whole block of characters at one time, instead of using `cin << ` to print each individual character: `for(size_t row = 0; row < characterMatrix.size(); ++row) { cin.write( characterMatrix[row].data(), characterMatrix[row].size()); }` or even `for(auto &row : characterMatrix) { cin.write(row.data(), row.size()); }`. However, note that `cout` is typically buffered by default, so changing how you write values probably won't make much difference

Comment: I assume this is for some sort of game where interaction counts in .. milliseconds? If so, use a library to help you to make it sort of portable or go native - just use the things available to you on the platform you're working.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau So will there be a difference between your suggested solution and `cout`? Since you said that `cout` is buffered. What about writing `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);`?

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo No, this is from my small project that I'm doing for fun. I want to optimize its I/O operations.

Comment: @digito_evo All libraries (like the `curses` derivatives) aim to do it very good. Take a peek at them.

Comment: @digito_evo sorry, I meant `cout` everywhere, not `cin`: `for(size_t row = 0; row < characterMatrix.size(); ++row) { cout.write(characterMatrix[row].data(), characterMatrix[row].size()); }` or `for(auto &row : characterMatrix) { cout.write(row.data(), row.size()); }`

Comment: Re: "Will this work faster?" -- **try it**.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Oh, I was really confused by `cin <<` and `cin.write`!!! I was searching on cppreference to find the article on that strange behavior! Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: How long is it taking now? How much faster do you want it to be? Yes printing one character at a time could be bad for performance, but unless you are printing millions and millions, it hardly ever matters.

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. It's hard for me to say how long it takes since I'm not printing millions but only thousands of `char`s. Also, I'm using a terminal that is slow in nature.

Comment: "It's hard for me to say how long it takes". Then you don't want to optimise it. "Also, I'm using a terminal that is slow in nature" Then you definitely don't want to optimise it. It is a waste of your time. Your time is more valuable than your computer's time.

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. I will check how long it takes to run in my own version vs the solution that was provided in one of the comments. If I see a noticeable difference, then I'll choose the better one.

Comment: @digito_evo "*It's hard for me to say how long it takes*" - then **time it**, such as with `std::chrono::steady_clock` or `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I used `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` just a few minutes ago. *JESUS CHRIST!!!!!!!* My solution finishes at **1000-1100** ms. Your solution finishes at **5-40** ms. What is happening here???!!!! This absolutely made my day!

Comment: @digito_evo Well, for one thing, `std::array<char, X_AxisLen> rowStr { }; ... std::cout << rowStr.data( );` doesn't do what you think it does. `data()` returns a `char*` in this case, and `operator<<` is overloaded to treat `char*` as a C-style null-terminated string, which your array is not (unless `characterMatrix` contains a `'\0'` in every row), and thus you are likely printing extra data from surrounding memory while it looks for a `'\0'`, which is *undefined behavior* and will take more time to complete (if it doesn't crash).

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Every one of the rows has a '\0' at its end. So it prevents undefined behavior. But I just don't understand why `<<` is so much slower than `write`. Is it because `write` prints unformatted output?

Comment: @digito_evo that is certainly part of it. `write()` simply copies the provided memory block as-is directly into the output buffer, whereas formatted output required additional processing based on the current flags of the stream (spacing, character casing, etc). But also, copying a whole block of memory in one go is simply going to be faster than copying 1 `char` at a time.

Comment: Have you tried `std::stringstream ss; ss << 123 ...; std::cout << ss.str();` This might be effective for a particular terminal. The terminal might be deliberately slow because it wants to scroll slowly so you can see the stuff.

Comment: @Barmak Shemirani The solution suggested by Remy Lebeau improved the speed of execution by ~130X. It seems that my terminal is not that slow. My code was too inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the whole row in one go and use `fmt::print` for better performance:

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>

#include <vector>

int main() {
  auto X_AxisLen = 10000u;
  auto Y_AxisLen = 10000u;
  auto characterMatrix =
      std::vector<std::vector<char>>(X_AxisLen, std::vector<char>(Y_AxisLen));
  for (int i = 0; i < Y_AxisLen; ++i) {
    const auto& row = characterMatrix[i];
    fmt::print("{}", std::string_view(row.data(), row.size()));
  }
}
```

```
% c++ test.cc -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=c++17 -I include src/format.cc -o test-fmt
% time ./test-fmt > /dev/null
./test-fmt > /dev/null  0.03s user 0.04s system 52% cpu 0.135 total
```

For comparison, this is ~30 times (not percent) faster than using `cout` and writing character by character:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  auto X_AxisLen = 10000u;
  auto Y_AxisLen = 10000u;
  auto characterMatrix =
      std::vector<std::vector<char>>(X_AxisLen, std::vector<char>(Y_AxisLen));
  for (int row = 0; row < Y_AxisLen; ++row) {
    for (int col = 0; col < X_AxisLen; ++col) {
      std::cout << characterMatrix[row][col];
    }
  }
}
```

```
% c++ test.cc -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=c++17 -I include src/format.cc -o test-cout
% time ./test-cout > /dev/null
./test-cout > /dev/null  4.30s user 0.08s system 95% cpu 4.581 total
```

This example is a bit artificial, in real world the difference may not be as dramatic particularly if you turn off sync with stdio. However, the {fmt} result can also be improved by using format string compilation and [the unsynchronized API](https://www.zverovich.net/2020/08/04/optimal-file-buffer-size.html) (if you are writing to a file).

Comment: Oh! Victor Zverovich himself!!! Unbelievable!!! I always wanted to use your library in my code but never did. Today is the day! I highly appreciate your help.